# How can I read images from firebase storage?

Tags: android

I uploaded multiple images to firebase storage as an array list. S0, I want to read only the first image from the array list.

[This is the database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LqXk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the link from the database, then load the url with either one of these packages into your `ImageView`:
Glide
https://github.com/bumptech/glide
Picasso
https://github.com/square/picasso

Comment: Can you please tell me, how to retrieve "0" position link?

Comment: @SMSakifSadadDil The docs on how to read data is here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Answer (score 0):

try this you can retrieve your image :-

```
DatabaseReference mReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Available Products")
                              .child("Apr 28,201900:56:18 am").child("ImageUris");

mReference.child("images").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String imageUrl = dataSnapshot.child("0").getValue().toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: I have edited the database structure. Please kindly see my database and write the code for reading "0" position image. It will be pleasure for me.

Comment: i have updated my answer you can try this to get your image

Comment: is this help you to get your image ?